# Rails PATCH Method Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using an AJAX call to patch a rails database. The update controller receives the call and looks up the element id in the database, but doesn't actually update it with the new attributes. It then sends a success message to the AJAX without logging any error. Any ideas?

Ajax:

```js
eventResizeStop: function(event){
    $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: "/appointments/"+event.id,
        data: { appointment: { end_time: event.end.format()} },
        success: function(data){
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors;
        }
    });
}
```

Rails controller:

```ruby
def update
  @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  if @appointment.update_attributes(appt_params)
    render nothing: true
    Rails.logger.info(@appointment.errors.full_messages)
  else
    render json: {errors: @appointment.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Started PATCH "/appointments/2" for 199.94.1.209 at 2015-01-29 18:28:53 +0000
Processing by AppointmentsController#update as */*
Parameters: {"appointment"=>{"end_time"=>"2015-01-30T15:00:00+00:00"}, "id"=>"2"}
Appointment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  commit transaction
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

**UPDATE**

Routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'houses/new'
  get 'houses/edit'
  get 'sessions/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'about'               =>  'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact'             =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'              =>  'users#new'
  get    'login'            =>  'sessions#new'
  post   'login'            =>  'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'           =>  'sessions#destroy'
  get 'newhouse'            =>  'houses#new'
  resources :users
  resources :houses
  resources :appointments,    only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: If you run the update_attributes in the rails console with the same data what do you get?

Comment: What does your `appt_params` method look like; perhaps you forgot to add the parameters, and thus you're getting back a blank hash?

Comment: @PaulRichter - that would have output a "Unpermitted parameter: end_time" in the log output shown above.

Comment: @smathy Oh yes, that's correct. Ignore my question.

Comment: @eabraham I tried using update_attributes in the console and it worked exactly like its supposed to - the field was updated to the new time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I'm a moron. I misread the fullcalendar documentation, and it turns out that the eventResizeStop callback doesn't include the new time, so AJAX was sending rails the same data it already had, hence the lack of an update to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def update
  @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  @appointment.end_time = params[:appointment][:end_time]
  if @appointment.save
    render nothing: true
    Rails.logger.info(@appointment.errors.full_messages)
  else
    render json: {errors: @appointment.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```

Comment: No such luck - for some reason the controller refuses to call the save method, and the development log isn't showing any errors.

Comment: Can you add your config/routes.rb to the question?